Why does TypeScript let me use a key which is not defined on my interface?
I have this line of code:
const _quantity = startPaymentFrontend?.products[productSlug]?.invoiceData?.[key2]

This here
startPaymentFrontend?.products[productSlug]

is a StartPaymentProduct
export interface StartPaymentProduct {
    pricingOptionId?: string
    passTypeId?: string
    quantity: number
    eventTimes?: { [eventTimeId: string]: StartPaymentProductEventTime }
    invoiceItems?: { [key: string]: number }
    teamSlug: string
}

Even developer environment recognizes it:

which does not have invoiceData - only invoiceItems.
Why does running yarn build not raise an error on it?
This here is the tsconfig.json:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "outDir": "./built"
    },
    "include": ["app/**/*", "index.d.ts", "index2.d.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

How can I force TypeScript to raise an error in those cases?

Is there another declaration of StartPaymentProduct in your codebase?

Maybe you can use the IDE "Go to definition" function to see where invoiceDate is defined.

Uhh yes ..that was to different implementation of StartPaymentProduct, strange I did notice before.

It is most likely due to the skipLibCheck option being set. This instructs the TS compiler to skip type checking of declaration files and despite the name, it won't only skip d.ts type checking in code that you can not control (i.e. node_modules), but instead it skips all *.d.ts files.
